# AS3 Inverted mask, MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER moves the mask

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, masking

I'm trying to make my images look awesome in AS3. I want to create the effect of the "moving background". For instance, my image is 200 x 200 and my mask is 200 x 40. When I hover, I want the background to move and the mask to stay put.

Since AS3 doesn't have an inverted mask option, I figured out I had to work with BlendMode and add the mask to my parent layer. Here is where the problem comes in I think. If I want to change the mask's Y-position (which I can't because masks dont have MouseEvents enabled), its all or nothing. Either the whole image comes down (including the mask), or nothing happens.

Here is some of my code, and I really do hope someone knows how to fix this rather easy looking problem. Ugh! (I have a custom ImageLoader class thats responsible for loading images)

```
var imageLoader:ImageLoader = new ImageLoader();
imageLoader.url = "image.jpg";
imageLoader.blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER;
imageLoader.addEventListener(ImageLoader.IMAGE_LOADED, imageLoadedHandler);

var maskContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
with (maskContainer.graphics) {
 beginFill(0x000000);
 drawRect(0, 0, 200, 40);
 endFill();
}

maskContainer.blendMode = BlendMode.ERASE;

private function imageLoadedHandler(e:Event):void {
 // Ofcourse, here is where the problem starts. 
 // I HAVE to addChild the mask to the imageLoader, so everything comes down/up.
 addChild(imageLoader);
 imageLoader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, rollOverHandler);
 imageLoader.addChild(maskContainer);
}

private function rollOverHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
 imageLoader.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, rollOverHandler);
 imageLoader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
}


private function mouseMoveHandler(e:MouseEvent):void{
 trace("move");
 imageLoader.y = e.currentTarget.mouseY;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to go through all this, why can't you just create the image, and the mask, and on mouse-over move the image, and keep the mask stationary?

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to do Daniel. Problem is, since I need an inverted mask (I only want to see whats inside the 200x40 rectangle), I need to addChild the mask to the image and change their blend modes, as explained here. http://franto.com/inverse-masking-disclosed

Comment: it seems like you're over-complicating it, try boiling it down to simpler blocks/prototypes that do what you need. Have a look at the example I showed below, you don't need to invert the mask, as that's what it is meant to do, you shouldn't need blending modes for this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I get the problem you're having.

The issue is that you are assigning things to the `imageLoader`, instead add an `imageHolder Sprite`

then instead of moving the sprite you can move the bitmap.
I just did this quickly in Flash, and added `IMG` into the library, but you can substitute a placeholder+loader, which is ideal anyway, because you can have a placeholder that says "loading" since you are loading stuff dynamically.

```
var imageHolder:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(imageHolder);
var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new IMG);
imageHolder.addChild(bmp);
var maskContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
with (maskContainer.graphics) {
 beginFill(0x000000);
 drawRect(0, 0, 200, 40);
 endFill();
}

imageHolder.mask = maskContainer;

imageHolder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, rollOverHandler);

function rollOverHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
 imageHolder.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, rollOverHandler);
 imageHolder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
}

function mouseMoveHandler(e:MouseEvent):void{
 trace("move");
 bmp.y = -e.currentTarget.mouseY;
}
```

Comment: For God's sake, I always make things way too complicated. Talking about a bad habit... Why couldn't I have come up with the idea of making another parentcontainer, it's so obvious. And what was I thinking, BlendModes?! Thanks a million Daniel!!